# Liberty and equality have become antagonist?

Tags: political-philosophy

From French revolution we got equality and liberty concept.in practical life it's seems two opposite pole .How will you satisfy this argument that both can be achieved simultaneously....As liberty leads to inequality and if we transfer some ones gain to poor it will not be accepted by libertarian...                                  Now a days  there is protectionist policy around the world as in usa and eu we witnessed this contradiction very well  and came to  a conclusion that both can't be claimed as equality and liberty are two different  thing like tom and Jerry?

Comment: I don't think liberty leads to the expanding inequality we see in the US. It should lead to something like a normal (in the mathematical sense) distribution of wealth based on a normal distribution of talent and effort. That's not a flat-line equality, but it's a good way to measure whether the amount of inequality is natural or artificially inflated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 The two can be brought together in the requirement of equal liberty for all, a principle we find in Rawls' Theory of Justice (1972).

2 To the extent that there is economic liberty - a market economy - in which free exchange takes place, there will be winners and losers and economic equality will be a vanishing quantity.

3 The flipside to this is that to the extent that economic equality is introduced and preserved, economic liberty will have to be curtailed since free exchange will produce economic inequalities.

4  Equality has many dimensions : economic equality, 'physical' equality (of age, health strength), political equality and others besides. The same holds for freedom : freedom of expression, freedom of worship, freedom of association, freedom to marry, freedom of movement, freedom from constraint or arbitrary arrest. *It is not at all clear that there is any general relation between all the dimensions of equality and all the dimensions of freedom.* Freedom of movement can go easily along with economic inequality; 'physical' inequality can  co-exist with political freedom.

5 There are dependencies, however : political freedom can be undermined by economic inequalities. We may all have one vote but institutions with economic power may by means of massive wealth (economic inequality) exert undue political influence and subvert political freedom.

Just some connexions and tensions you might care to consider.

Comment: 2008 market failure and recent banks fraud  in india also shown that there is some problem with liberty ...And it came to a conclusion that liberty alone could not be able to stop clashes in world...Most important thing I understood is that libertarian talk about universal nature of rights so if we want to fulfill freedom of any kind  political and economical we must have equal opportunity so it necessarily taking us toward equality ...And at the same time every human conflicts  has seed  of  inequality which we recognize as Injustice and  ultimate goal is freedom ..

Comment: So there is internal relation betw

Comment: But in reality there is problem as some how govt impose extra tax to rich to compensate poor and it is justifiable because industrial activity eroded there right to land and water ...If it so we  can ask world right to compensate and right to green technology at the same time ...But again neither they are accepted paris agreement nor helping in achieving green development...As trump policy visa and withdrawn from Paris agreement..It's all again taken us to liberty equality problem..

Answer (score 0):

I agree that they oppose each other, as you can't have liberty with equality, and you can't have equality with liberty.

Equality taken as an ideal leads to communism, which is shown to fail whenever it is tried.

Liberty taken as an ideal leads to anarchy, which is mostly untested but seems unworkable.

Equality of liberty would be what I'd suggest we aim for. The same level of freedom for all, seems to make the most sense.